# Java netbeans run.bat file error in loading main class

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, netbeans, cmd

I have a TestAccount in the default packages which located in 
--JavaApplication/build/classes
To begin, i click on the folder options and and untick the "Hide extensions for known file types" So that i can create a .bat file in build folder.

I created a textdocument and changed .txt to run.bat . The code is as follows:

```
echo on
java TestAccount
pause
```

After save the bat file, i can run the java program in CMD. However, when i try to move the TestAccount.class file to another new folder call "testing". i repeat the step but with some modification on the code.

Here is the new bat file code on testing's folder

```
echo on
java testing.TestAccount
pause
```

Then the problem occur. I got this error in CMD. 
Error: Could not find or load main class testing.TestAccount.

Anyone know how to make solve this problem? So that i can run the program in other folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After several tried and errors, i finally got the solution. Just simple add in one line "cd.." after echo on, then the program can run.

```
echo on
cd..
java testing.TestAccount
pause
```

although i don't understand why it will works...